# What is the difference among NSString alloc:initWithCString versus stringWithUTF8String?

Tags: sqlite, nsstring, allocation, copy-constructor

I thought these two methods were (memory allocation-wise) equivalent, however, I was seeing "out of scope" and "NSCFString" in the debugger if I used what I thought was the convenient method (commented out below) and when I switched to the more explicit method my code stopped crashing!  Notice that I am getting the string that is being stored in my container from sqlite3 query.

```
p = (char*) sqlite3_column_text (queryStmt, 1);
// GUID = (NSString*) [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (p!=NULL) ? p : ""];
GUID = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:(p!=NULL) ? p : "" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also note, that if I looked at the values in the debugger and printed them with NSLog they looked correct, however, I don't think new memory was allocated and the value copied.  Instead the memory pointer was stored - went out of scope - referenced later - crash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep a reference to an object around after a method returns, then you need to take ownership of the object. So, if your variable `GUID` is an instance variable or some kind of global, you will need to take ownership of the object. If you use the alloc/init method, you have ownership of the object returned since you used `alloc`. You could just as easily use the `stringWithUTF8String:` method, but you will need to take ownership explicitly by sending a `retain` message. So, assuming `GUID` is some kind of non-method-scoped variable:

```
GUID = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Some UTF-8 string"] copy];
```

(either `copy` or `retain` can be used here to take ownership, but `copy` is more common when dealing with strings).

Also, your code may be a little easier to read if you did something like:

```
GUID = p ? [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:p] copy] : @"";
```

Comment: Now that explanation makes sense! Also, I think it explains some other mystery crashes.

Comment: Let's note that `stringWithUTF8String:` already performs a copy according to doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497379-stringwithutf8string